# 3D vectors and programming - general question

Tags: c#, vector

I have asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964670/vectors-and-unit-vector-in-programming/2964686#2964686) but feel it might actually be a programming question.

First, my math is horrible, that is why I am brushing up at Khan. I have been watching and learning about vectors by the most awesome Sal Khan at Khan academy. My question is more of a general one regarding representing 3D entities on something like a CAD program. Entities like planes, vectors, etc.

All of what Sal does is based with the origin as the starting point of the vector. He is careful to point out that a vector can start at any coordinate though. I suspect that this is to make things much simpler and explain the properties.

My question is this...when a person is representing and doing math in programming (let's say a line that goes from 2,2,2 -> 5,5,5) of a vector does one transform the vector to (0,0), do the math and then transform the result back to it's original position or is something done to it "in place"?

Comment: In my limited experience from 3D computer graphics programming the points (e.g. the endpoints of a vector) are kept as arrrays and are manipulated as-is by adding (shift) or multiplying (stretch, rotate) with matrices. If you google "!transformations of 3D coordinates matrix" Khan videos come up high in the list ;-).

Comment: In the end, most transformations can be defined around arbitrary points and vectors and so on. Translating to an axis or the origin can make some transformations simpler to visualize. There's definitely value in the extra simplicity, and definitely value in trying to utilize this in the design of your program (and also noting that most vectors are merely magnitudes and directions, and have no starting point). But if you have to go out of your way to move things around, it's often easier to simply do the transformations in place.

Answer (score 1):

First please note that **"a line that goes from 2,2,2 -> 5,5,5"** is not a vector. It is a line that has a start point and and end point. Or we can say that line has a start point of (2,2,2) and a direction of (3,3,3). In this sense the direction is a vector. In other words a line is a compound of a starting point and a vector.

So when you have a vector, in this case (3,3,3) it does not have a starting point. It's just a direction. So **"transform the vector to (0,0)"** has no meaning.